# C Language Pointers Question

Tags: microcontroller, c, texas-instruments, hex, pointers

Not sure if this is the correct place to post a programming based question so will have a go anyway.

Attached below is a piece of code and a table where I have to fill in the blanks. ***Just to clarify, the question essentially is, ("The table should contain both the address and value of each integer variable after the last line of code has been executed.")***

The bottom table is my attempt and the boxes with a '?' are where I don't understand:

[image]

I do understand pointers but I am getting confused with the pointer to a pointer variables I think.

By the way this is based of a 32-bit micro-controller, hence the hex values.

Would be great if someone could explain the step by step logic I should be taking with this code to fill in the table.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: A pointer's value is the address at which some other value is stored, regardless of the type of the value that it points to.  A pointer is a type, just like an int.

Comment: Are you starting with the assumption that the address of 'a' is 0x20000000?

Comment: Can you not `return(**z)` or `return(a+b)`?

Comment: @ajb, So when I see anything with the &, this is pointing to the address. And when I see an *, this is referring to the value of the memory location that the variable is pointing to?

Comment: Also, it's not immediately clear if "Value" is meant to refer to the value stored in the indicated variable, or the fully-dereferenced value.  I would assume the former, but either one would make an interesting homework question.  If I were the instructor I would have asked for both.

Comment: @m.Alin, yes sorry should have said. This is the starting address for a specific port of the micro-controller

Comment: @KingDuken, This is a paper based question, and I don't understand exactly what's happening, so running code likely won't help

Comment: Edited question to provide more info.

Comment: The question as stated is still not really clear--only two of those variables are integers!  However I take it to mean the fully dereferenced value, which would be an integer for all of the variables in question.  In any case, constructing a complete table of direct values and dereferenced values will probably help you.

Comment: @ajb While I'm not sure if the professor or the OP is the one making the question technically ambiguous, this seems like a pretty straightforward and very common pointer exercise that asks for the value and the address of all of the different variables in the function. As in, some entries of the "values" column should be addresses of the form `0x2000....` and other entries should be the integers `2` or `4`.

Comment: The ambiguity is in the table "variable" column, where instead of `int **z` it really ought to just say `z`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be migrated to stackoverflow.com as it is pure software.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily off-topic but it's definitely unclear because you have no idea where the variables end up unless more info is provided.

Comment: The exact duplicate at SO: [Pointer to pointer clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604946/pointer-to-pointer-clarification). No point in migrating, the post will get closed as a duplicate to that one.

Comment: And yes, pure programming questions not related to hardware or embedded systems programming are off-topic, as they should be asked at https://stackoverflow.com/ (and you'll get much better answers there).

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` unary operator is called the *dereference* (or *indirection*) operator, and it dereferences a pointer to the value stored to where it points.

For example:

```
int main(){
    int a;
    int *b;

    a = 3;
    b = &a;

    return (*b);
}
```

The function above would return the value `3`.

The operator can also be cascaded. For example, `*(*z)`. Here `*z` would return whatever value is stored in the location that `z` points to. In the case that z was pointing to a pointer (i.e. `int **z = &y` and `y` is a pointer), then the second indirection would return the value at the location pointed to by the pointer that `z` points to (in this case, the value of `y`).

The `&` unary operator is called the *address-of* operator. It's function is pretty self-explanatory:

```
int main(){
    int w;    // assume this is stored at 0x0000
    int x;    // assume this is stored at 0x0004
    int y;    // assume this is stored at 0x0008

    w = 3;
    x = w;
    y = &x;

    ....
```

In this example, `x == 3` and `y == 4` (or `y = 0x0004h`).

Comment: If my answer doesn't help clear anything up, you will likely have better luck migrating this question to StackOverflow, IMO. It doesn't have anything to do with EE.SE.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is question is completely irrelevant to EE, since electrical engineering can include programming of microcontrollers, as the OP had mentioned. Just because this is fundamentally more of a programming question than a EE question, anyone here should be able to answer this question just as much as someone on StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Appreciate the help.